# react native vision camera freezing on taking a picture

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I just need to take and store a picture. I am using react-native-vision-camera but when I take a picture, using `.takePhoto()` method. It freezes.

I am also using "qualityPrioritization: "speed".

I am testing it on an android emulator.

```
const CameraPage = () => {
  const devices = useCameraDevices()
  const device = devices.back
  const isFocused = useIsFocused()
  const camera = useRef(null)

  const onPressButton = async () => {
    console.log(camera.current)
    console.log(123)
    const photo = await camera.current.takePhoto({
      flash: 'off',
      qualityPrioritization: "speed"
    })

    console.log(photo)

  }
  
  if (device == null) return <View><Text>Loading</Text></View>
  return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <Camera
          ref={camera}
          style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
          device={device}
          isActive={isFocused}
          photo={true}
          />
           <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity 
              style={styles.camButton}
              onPress={onPressButton}
              >
                <Text>Click me</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>

  )
```

Comment: You can just use a real device to bypass the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I met the same problem, and here is the way I solve it.

#### Conclusion

If you just need a **demo** on an android emulator, you can use `takeSnapshot(...)` instead.

#### Explanation

Let's go back to the guide of `takePhoto()` of [react-native-vision-camera](https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/capturing).

Right below it is `takeSnapshot()`, and there has a note that writes:

> if you care about speed, you can use the Camera's `takeSnapshot(...)` function (Android only) which simply takes a snapshot of the Camera View **instead of actually taking a photo through the Camera lens**.

I guess the problem that react-native-vision-camera will freeze maybe because an android emulator doesn't have a **real** Camera lens.

So I tried `takeSnapshot(...)` instead and it worked perfectly.

That's all, hope this can help.

Comment: Cheers, thank you. 
I just ended up using a real device for my purposes.

Comment: But i don't think that android emulator not having a real camera lens is an issue since, you can easily use the default camera app in android simulator.

Comment: How can i use image on takeSnapshot? thank @D.H